# where to find the space quota for a Sharepoint document library

Tags: document-library, storage, quota

I Am new to SharePoint, I have some question about the SharePoint document library, I want to find the space quota for a Sharepoint document library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint quotas are not allocated on a per library basis, but for a site collection.

You need to be an administrator for the farm or for the tenant, with access to the administration site to see quotas for a site collection.